# Check empty vector in initializer list

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, initialization

I would like initialize base class by a first item form a vector which contains base classes, e.g.:

```
struct Base { ... };

struct Derived : public Base
{
   Derived(const Base& baseClass)
      : Base(baseClass)
   {
   }
   Derived(const std::vector<Base*>& listOfBaseClass)
      : Base(*(listOfBaseClass[0]))
   {
   }
};
```

This solution fails when `listOfBaseClass` vector will be empty. How can prevent this situation. This is simplified example, so
calling base class constructor like this:

```
std::vector<Base> baseClasses;

if(!baseClasses.empty())
{
  Derived myDerived(baseClasses[0]);
}
```

it is not solution for my problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Throw an exception if the list is empty:

```
 : Base(listOfBaseClass.empty() 
          ? throw std::invalid_argument("Missing base class")
          : *(listOfBaseClass[0])
        )
```

Non-exception variant by request:

```
 : Base(( (listOfBaseClass.empty() && exit(0)),
          *(listOfBaseClass[0])
       ))
```

Comment: Unfortunately in my project I must not use exceptions.

Comment: Well, then you have a problem. Exceptions were exactly designed for this situation (failing inside constructor), and C++ has no alternative (People already complain C++ is complex, adding redundant features to work around silly restrictions won't help). I suggest you simply do not call `Derived` with a wrong argument then.

Comment: @rgb, you have already accepted this answer (otherwise I would have posted a new one). When the construction of an object is non-trivial, the canonical solution is a factory function. The function would look in the list of base classes and initialize the class to be returned, and in case there isn't one, it would be the factory function that should throw/exit/signal error/etc.

Comment: @utnapistim: I wouldn't consider it canonical. It's more of a Java-ism. C++ typically uses factories when it's not even  clear what _type_ of object you need.

Comment: @MSalters, consider the std::make_shared, std::make_unique, std::make_tuple, std::make_pair - you know with all of them the resulting type. Either way, I proposed the factory function solution because I don't think you should ever call exit in library/server code, and it is easier to add a factory function (like create_x_or_exit) than it is to add a (possibly) failing constructor.

Answer (score 3):

```
Derived(const std::vector<Base*>& listOfBaseClass)
      : Base(*(listOfBaseClass->at(0)))
   {
   }
```

"at" provides exception safety. It throws out_of_range if n is out of bounds.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/